# Use database connection to Unit testing project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, unit-testing, nunit

How to use database connection with our Unit testing project. We have some thousands of unit test code that follows NUnit framework for our MVC application. We have lot of business logic codes that connect with SQL database with MVC application. So we have written unit testing codes that apply the same business logic which connect with database.

For example we have written to insert, update, retrieve operation in unit testing which connect to database.

We have two different source one for Local or Staging application, and another Production application. So different database for Local and Production. Now our testing codes are connected with local database. Is this better way to use different database for unit testing codes to run?

Is changing connection string to change different database connection in web config file of Unit testing projection enough and right way to do or else do we have any other proper way to switch database based on different Solution configurations?

Help us the address this scenario.

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: You dont. A unit test does not use 'real' data. You mock your data.

Comment: @Stephen: We have large amount of DB access, more number of tables, stored procedures, scenarios like ensure the output from stored procedures. How to mock these things?

Comment: the "how" a stored procedure does something does not matter in the scope of a unit test (unless unit testing the proc itself).  You need to mock your returned data through the use of dependency injection (as an example).

Comment: @Kritner is right, what you've set up there sounds more like system/integration testing, with scope being wider than that of a single _unit_